# Why am I getting a 'no such file or directory' error when importing images in tkinter using nuitka in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, nuitka

I am developing a tool in python with tkinter.
The structure of my project is the following:

- project folder:

  - src

    - main.py
    - ...other files.py
    - changelog.md
  - res

    - img

      - images used by my project

In my main code I import several images in the following way:
`question_icon = PhotoImage(file = "../res/img/question_icon_32.png")`

When I try to build a one file executable with nuitka, if I execute it the \src folder then everything works, but if I try to move it to some other folder then I get this error when importing the images:

couldn't open "../res/img/question_icon_32.png": no such file or directory.

I figure the problem is the way I import the images, but I wasn't able to understand exactly what am I doing wrong.
I have python 3.11 and nuitka 1.5.8
I call nuitka with:
`python -m nuitka --onefile --onefile-tempdir-spec="%TEMP%\onefile_%PID%_%TIME%" -o myprogram.exe --enable-plugin=tk-inter --include-data-dir="C:\...project_folder\res"=res --include-data-file="C:\...project_folder\src\changelog.md"=changelog.md C:\...project_folder\src\main.py`

of course "C:...project_folder" is the full absolute path to the project folder.

Do you have any suggestion what am I doing wrong?

I thought the "../" was problematic so I tried putting the \res folder inside the \src folder and change the import to `question_icon = PhotoImage(file = "/res/img/question_icon_32.png")`  but I still get the same error

Comment: Avoid relative pathes. They are usually constructed by prepending your CWD, which may vary, depending on how you start your app. Try to build absolute pathes yourself, e.g. using your main module's ``__file__`` attribute.

Comment: I am not familiar with nuitka, but a quick google search brought up ``--file-reference-choice=FILE_REFERENCE_MODE`` which may have an impact on how ``__file__`` behaves.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MikeScotty , I tried to import the files using absolute paths, the problem is that when I try to launch my program exe in another machine it will crash with "no such file or directory" error, because it will look for the path that is only valid in my machine. I understand that using --standalone options you get a folder with all the dependencies, but that would defeat the purpose of having a single .exe deliverable file

Answer (score 1):

Nuitka handles relative imports differently in the main file vs the files that get included by the main file. I've gotten around this by creating a wrapper .py that just calls my main .py. Then all my relative paths in my original main function worked properly.

Update: I've learned that Nuitka handles relative paths to .py files differently than for other files (such as txt or other data files that your code calls). The wrapper function hack fixes the problem for .py files. When using --standalone and non-py files, the paths need to be hard coded to the location in the .dist folder. (You also need to use --include or copy the files to the .dist folder.)

Answer (score 0):

When the single-file executable is executed, it will run in a temp folder specified in the nuitka command, which will include all the resourced included in nuitka. My problem was that this folder do not respect the same structure of my project folder, therefore I needed to fix the path to import the resources.

I eventually solved by importing the resources like this:

```
    question_icon = PhotoImage(file = resource_path("..\\res\\img\\question_icon_32.png"))
```

where

```
enter code here
def resource_path(relative_path):

   # The prefix ..\ is removed from the relative path
   temp_folder_path_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), relative_path[3:])
   if os.path.isfile(temp_folder_path_file):
       return temp_folder_path_file
   else:
       return os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), relative_path)
```